# Is there any difference between fromlist() method and extend() method of Python array module?

Tags: python, arrays

The fromlist() method and extend() method are both used to extend the array by list in the array module.
There is no difference in how it is returning and handling runtime errors.

*Almost both behave the same, but why there are two different methods with the same functionality?
I checked in Python docs, Source code but didn't find anything unique.*

let me know if I'm missing out on anything here.
Thanks in Advance!

```
#Sample code
from array import array
arr = array('i',[1,2,3,4,4])
templist = [5,6] 
arr.extend(templist) 
#arr.fromlist(templist)
```

Comment: The docs give this exact information. Mainly, extend() accepts any iterable and fromlist() only accepts lists https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.extend

Comment: That, and the behavior if an error occurs is different.